# Modifying corpus in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dataset (customer review corpus) looking like this:

```
documents = 
[["I like the product", "5"],["the product is poor", "2.5"],["it is an okay product", "3"],["the quality is poor", "1"],["color is great", "3.5"]]
```

The first list value is corpus I would like to modify based on the second value, which is score. The score could be any number between 1 (lowest) and 5 (highest). What I want is to insert the word "GOOD" to the corpus, if its score is greater than 3, and the word "BAD" to the corpus, if the score is less than 3. So the output should look like this:

```
[["I like the product GOOD", "5"],["the product is poor BAD", "2.5"],["it is an okay product", "3"],["the quality is poor BAD", "1"],["color is great GOOD", "3.5"]]
```

I have developed a code causing 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

```
for document in documents:
    if int(float(document[1])) > 3:
        document[0].insert('GOOD')
    elif int(float(document[1])) < 3:
        document[0].insert('BAD')
    else:
        document[0].insert()
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was  `document[0].insert()` supposed to do?

Comment: I wanted to insert "BAD" or "GOOD" to the original corpus, based on the score value. @acushner answered my question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep, `str` objects don't have `insert` methods.

just add it:

```
document[0] += ' GOOD'
```

Comment: Note that even if they *had* such a method, the original code couldn't possibly work. Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension structure together with conditionals (ternary):

```
docs = [[doc[0] + (" GOOD" if float(doc[1]) > 3 
                 else (" BAD" if float(doc[1]) < 3 else ""))] 
        for doc in documents]

>>> docs
[['I like the product GOOD'],
 ['the product is poor BAD'],
 ['it is an okay product'],
 ['the quality is poor BAD'],
 ['color is great GOOD']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from strings being *immutable* and not having an insert method, your else is redundant, the string can only be > < or == which if the first two are False means it has to be equal so nothing should be done to it:

```
for doc in documents:
    f = int(float(doc[1]))
    if f > 3:
        doc[0] += " GOOD"
    elif f < 3:
        doc[0] += " BAD"
 print(documents)

[['I like the product GOOD', '5'], ['the product is poor BAD', '2.5'],
 ['it is an okay product', '3'], ['the quality is poor BAD', '1'], 
['color is great', '3.5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with list comprehension

```
documents = [['I like the product', '5'],['the product is poor', '2.5'],['it is an okay product', '3'],['the quality is poor', '1'],['color is great', '3.5']]

documents = [[x[0] + (' GOOD' if float(x[1]) > 3 else ' BAD' if float(x[1]) < 3 else ''), x[1]] for x in documents]
```